# Slime\Emacs comint hangs when launching mpi process

Tags: emacs, mpi, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I have a simple mpi program to demonstrate my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank, csize;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &csize);

    printf("Hello from rank[%d/%d]\n", rank, csize);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

After compiling, I can successfully launch the executable using `mpirun` from the sbcl repl:

```
* (uiop:run-program '("mpirun" "-np" "10" "./hello_world") :output :string)

"Hello from rank[7/10]
Hello from rank[9/10]
Hello from rank[5/10]
Hello from rank[8/10]
Hello from rank[0/10]
Hello from rank[1/10]
Hello from rank[2/10]
Hello from rank[3/10]
Hello from rank[4/10]
Hello from rank[6/10]
"
NIL
0
```

However, when I run the same from within slime, the slime repl simply hangs.  If I run the executable directly, rather than through the `mpirun` launcher, then the everything runs fine:

```
CL-USER> (uiop:run-program '("./hello_world")
               :output :string)
"Hello from rank[0/1]
"
NIL
0
```

I'm using sbcl-1.4.5 and slime 2.20 on a linux workstation.  Does anyone have a solution to this problem or a starting point of where to look?

UPDATE:

The problem stems from emacs `comint` mode, which slime is based on.  I observer the same hanging behavior if I launch `sbcl` via `make-comint-in-buffer` and then use `uiop:run-program`.

UPDATE2:

After reading up a bit on `comint` mode, I was able to capture some output from the hanging process.  This emacs lisp code:

```
(make-comint "foo" "mpirun" nil "-np" "1" "/home/ptb/programming/c/hello_world")
```

produces the follow error on the hung process:

```
[warn] Epoll MOD(1) on fd 14 failed.  Old events were 6; read change was 0 (none); write change was 2 (del): Bad file descriptor
[warn] Epoll MOD(4) on fd 14 failed.  Old events were 6; read change was 2 (del); write change was 0 (none): Bad file descriptor
```

Any ideas as to what this means?

Comment: I guess that this is a problem with redirected stdin/stdout in openmpi or libevent (there have been such problems in the past, e. g. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1235044).  Which version of those do you use?

Comment: @Svante Genius!  I had built a newer version of openmpi (3.0.0) rather than using the one supplied by fedora.  I switched back to the rpm version and everything works fine now.  Feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that this is a problem with redirected stdin/stdout in openmpi or libevent (there have been such problems in the past, e. g. bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1235044). Which version of those do you use?